# Why are the stats for HTML Improvements in Google Webmaster Tools not decreasing?

Tags: google-search-console, html

I have read that resolving HTML Improvements in Google Webmaster Tools can take as long as 6 weeks to show up, but those numbers seem to increase without decreasing even though I've been fixing almost everything that Google points out.

I have checked some sites with the View as Google tool and the bugs are resolved (let's say "short meta descriptions" for example).

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Google has so many sites to index, it just takes time. Be patient.

Comment: @Zistoloen is absolutely right. Google may not visit some of these for a long while and not notice the change until all of the pages have be re-fetched. It is best to wait. But if there are only a few, then you use Fetch as Googlebot in Webmaster Tools and that should clear things up faster. What is important to know here is that Google is only informing you of improvements you can make. If you fixed the problem, there is no harm if Google does not notice the fixes for a while and still reports a problem.

Comment: @closetnoc Seems like a decent answer to me.